# Best way to get the list-like string back into a list

Tags: python, list

Quick question, some data was corrupted and now all the lists I had have turned into strings:

e.g:
`["en", "ru"]`,

is now :

```
str(["en", "ru"])
```

What is the best way to turn it back to list?

Comment: Found a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `ast.literal_eval`. Do not use `eval` it is [unsafe](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(str(["en", "ru"]))
['en', 'ru']
```

Answer (score 1):

`eval(str(["a", "b"]))`

gets you ["a", "b"]